# labeling 10 years of data by with 1-10 opposed to 1955-1966

Tags: r, date, plot, axis

I have 6 data sets each with a decade of daily data that I want to plot on the same graph. In order to do this, I want to convert each year in the decade to a number starting with 1 and ending at 10. For each data set the year begins on YYYY-10-01 and ends on YYYY-09-30 with a date format of YYYY-MM-DD.

I really have no where to being but, have played around with the seq() function. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Below is the code for how I read the data file.

```
WY10 <- fread("1956-1966.txt", select = c(3:4)) #reads the text file,selects col the 3 and 4
names(WY10)[names(WY10) == 'V4'] <- 'Discharge' #changes name of col 4 to Discharge
names(WY10)[names(WY10) == 'Date'] <- 'Year' #changes name of col 3 to Date
seq(as.Date("1955-10-01"), as.Date("1966-09-30","Years"))

p1 <- plot(WY10,type= "l",ylab='',xlab='')
```

I have daily data for WY10-60.(1955-2016)
Very new to R but very capable of using google, however, wasn't able to find a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Example data of 6 of 4018 observations.

```
{structure(list(Year = structure(-5206:-5201, class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), Discharge = c(19, 15, 17, 15, 17, 15)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")}
```

I had success with @dww answer however am having difficulties actually applying the change to my plot. My code now looks like this.

```
{x <- seq.Date(as.Date("1955-10-01"), as.Date("1966-09-30"), 1)
breaks <- seq(as.Date("1955-10-01"), length = 4018, by = "year")
cut(x, breaks, labels = FALSE )
plot(WY10, type = "l",ylab= 'Discharge (cfs)',xlab= 'Year', xlim=c(1,11)) 
axis(side = 1, at = 1:11)}
```

It doesn't seem like the plot function recognizes the change in date sequence.

Comment: Can you show a small reproudible example and expected output

Comment: updated my question to show my plot and the code I used to plot the data set.

Comment: The issue is thaat your data is not reproducible because you are reading it from your local machine.  Can you use `dput` to show few lines of your data.  It is not clear about the expected output

Comment: If you have 6 datasets. and want to plot, may be you want to combine those data with `rbind` i.e. `datnew <- do.call(rbind, list(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6))`

Comment: bare with me as I am a new user.

Comment: I think the below answer by dww should be correct

Comment: let me give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example data

```
set.seed(1111)
x = seq.Date(as.Date("1955-10-01"), as.Date("1966-09-30"), 1)
x = sort(sample(x, 20))
```

Now, you can use cut

```
breaks <- seq(as.Date("1955-10-01"), length=13, by="year")
cut(x, breaks, labels = FALSE )
# [1]  1  1  1  2  3  3  3  5  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  9 10 10 10 11
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I think it would work if I only had annual data but, I have daily data so a total of 4018 observations, one for each day. Sorry i did not make that clear.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I should expect 365 "1's" 365 "2's" and so on so forth until I am up to 11?

Comment: The results depend what dates are in your data.  You did not provide any data (which you should), so I made a small example dataset with 20 random dates in it.  In any case the algorithm is correct.

Comment: I updated my question to include 6 of the 4018 observations.

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't able to do exactly what I wanted with the data, I ended up finding a work around the worked very well.

First, I read my data and set my y variable as an object:
The below code reads my text file for WY10 and turns it into a data frame.
I did this for all 6 decades of data frames WY10-WY60

```
WY10 <- fread("1956-1966.txt", header = TRUE, select = c(3:4))
names(WY10)[names(WY10) == 'V4'] <- 'Discharge'
Y1 <- WY10$Discharge
```

The cheat I did was plot just the Y1 variable and remove the x variable from the plot with xaxt:
The below code creates the initial plot for WY10.

```
plot(Y1, xaxt= "n", type = "l",ylab= 'Discharge (cfs)') + 
(xlab= 'Year', col = "black", ylim=c(0,2500))
```

I then wrote in the rest of the YX variables for each data frame:

```
lines(Y2, xaxt = "n", type = "l", col = "blue" )
lines(Y3, xaxt = "n", type = "l", col = "orange" )
lines(Y4, xaxt = "n", type = "l", col = "red" )
lines(Y5, xaxt = "n", type = "l", col = "green" )
lines(Y6, xaxt = "n", type = "l", col = "yellow" )
```

Finally, I changed the sequence of the x axis for the plot:

```
axis(1, at=seq(0,4017,365), labels=0:11)
```

I think this was a quick and easy fix but is obviously a work around as it does not actually manipulate are sequence the x variable of my data frames.